# Take A Set Location and add on to its Height and Width

Tags: vb.net, button, location

I have buttons on a form, that when you click on them some disappear. I want to show a label underneath where the button used to be

So far I have:

```
lbl.location = btn.location
```

but I want to take the button location and add on to the height and width, so it looks centered where the button used to be

Is there anyway to take a set location and add on to it?

Comment: ensure the label has multiline set to true, and make it's width and height the same as the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nOffsetX/nOffsetY being whatever offset you want...

```
lbl.Location.X = btn.Location.X + nOffsetX
lbl.Location.Y = btn.Location.Y + nOffsetY
```

Alternatively, you could set the size of the label and button to the same size and then center the label text, that way the UI looks better as the labels will be aligned in the center of where the buttons were.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Location, Size and TextAlign properties to get the label where it should be:

```
lbl.Location = btn.Location
lbl.Size = btn.Size
lbl.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
```

But you will also want to set `lbl.AutoSize = False` so that the label doesn't retain its original sizing.

To set X and Y independently, just use them as follows:

```
lbl.Location.X = btn.Location.X + 10
lbl.Location.Y = btn.Location.Y + 10
```

Comment: Thank you, I wish i could mark two answers as correct, this worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The Location property is of type Point, which has X and Y properties you can set independently.  Does this help?

Comment: yes, i have x and y coordinates for the button that i want to set to the label but also add on. For example if button locations is (50,100) i want the label to be (50+10,100+10)

Comment: `lbl.Location.X = btn.Location.X + 10` and
`lbl.Location.Y = btn.Location.Y + 10`

Comment: Yes...  Lbl.Location.X =Btn.Location.X + 10

Comment: Gives me an error that "Expression is a value and therefore cannot be a target of an assignment"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increment the X component:

```
lbl.location = new size(btn.Location.X + 10, btn.Location.Y)
```

or increment the Y

```
lbl.Location = new size(btn.Location.X, btn.Location.Y + 10)
```